# run JavaScript if database value equals x

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, sql-server

I have a piece of JavaScript that I want on a custom-built intranet to run only for a specific set of users.

When the page is loaded, there is a script in the header that queries the MS SQL database for an ID that would be specific for a group of users (eg. a office location).

The new JavaScript I want to run needs to be added just before the , but I want it to only show for the users of a specific office ID.

The script in the header I refer to uses:

```
<telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="script1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
<script type="text/javascript">

currentCollectionId = '<%= GetCurrentCollectionID() %>';
myFirmID = '<%= GetMyFirmID() %>';

$(function() etc...
```

And the ***myFirmID*** that I want the added JavaScript to run for is ***487136f1-4e60-4d1c-a98a-4c01e5b14ed6***.

Is there a way I can have a script run to either check the presence of this ID on the loaded page, and then insert/run the new JavaScript...

Or, query the database for the ID equal to that value, and then add/run the new script?

The new script I want to run is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.zendesk.com/external/zenbox/v2.6/zenbox.js"></script>
<style type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
  @import url(//assets.zendesk.com/external/zenbox/v2.6/zenbox.css);
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof (Zenbox) !== "undefined") {
        Zenbox.init({
            dropboxID: "xxxxxxxx",
            url: "https://foobar.zendesk.com",
            tabTooltip: "Support",
            tabImageURL: "https://assets.zendesk.com/external/zenbox/images/tab_support.png",
            tabColor: "#d8732d",
            tabPosition: "Left"
        });
    }
</script>
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle checking the ID server side:

```
<% If "487136f1-4e60-4d1c-a98a-4c01e5b14ed6".Equals(GetMyFirmID()) Then %>
<script>
   ... 
</script>
<% End If %>
```

The script will only be written if the firm ID is the one in question.

If GetMyFirmID() is expensive and you need to use the result more than once (I see you also use it on the myfirmid line), you probably want to stick the result in a variable instead of repeatedly calling the method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is a good solution because it avoids exposing that firm ID to the client, and it won't even let the client see the code that it's not supposed to be executing. Well done.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not overly familiar with ASP.
Where in the page would I insert that?  Do I need anything before or after it?  Eg. `<telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="script1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
 <script type="text/javascript">` etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misinterpreted as JSP. The answer, conceptually, is still the same, although the syntax may not be. You would put it in your ASP page source, around where the script currently is. You should probably check out a basic ASP primer first to familiarize yourself with ASP tags.

Comment: I'm glancing around at ASP references, it looks like the syntax is precisely the same as above, except with a capital E for Equals. Can somebody familiar with ASP confirm this before I edit?

Comment: I've tried just inserting that into the <body> just before the close (using my JavaScript where you specify), and have refreshed the page.  I get a compilation error _BC30081: 'If' must end with a matching 'End If'._ with reference to that first line.

Comment: That's my fault, for using JSP. I have updated the answer above. Sorry for the confusion. Please let me know how it goes. See http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/asp/3 for more syntax examples.